# Why wouldn't you be able to hide a file in OS X with chflags?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

So, bit of an oddball question. There's a particular file—an alias—that for some reason will *not* hide from the UI with `chflags hidden`. Doesn't matter what I do. sudo is ineffective against this particular file.

It's not a problem, I'm just more curious WHY and how it is that this particular stubborn little guy can't be hidden. The file is an alias for the Adobe Acrobat X Uninstaller. I was able to hide all the other garbage that Adobe puts in /Applications with `sudo chflags hidden`, but this guy was resistant.

Curious if anyone has encountered this and, if so, understands why certain files can not be hidden from the UI with `chflags`.

Get Info attached:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a symbolic link, you have to use `chflags -h`.

```
 -h      If the file is a symbolic link, change the file flags of the link itself
         rather than the file to which it points.
```